# MATLAB: Parpool shared data access

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, interpolation, parfor

I use:

```
if isempty(gcp('nocreate'))
  parpool([ 1, Inf ]);
end
```

... to create a parpool in my wrapper function `wrapper.m`, which gives me 4 workers on my desktop. `wrapper.m` calls a file `foo.m`, which in turn calls `bar.m` several times.

The wrapper function generates heavy data, which is required in `bar.m` on a purely read-only basis:

`wrapper.m`:

```
  genSpline = griddedInterpolant({ gridData.xgv, gridData.ygv, gridData.zgv }, ...
              gridData.data, 'spline', 'spline');
```

`bar.m`:

```
  val = genSpline(interPts);
```

When passed as an argument to `bar.m` via `foo.m`, each worker in the pool maintains its own private copy of `genSpline`, causing an enormous memory leak thanks to redundant data. However, the program works fine as such.

In an effort to work around this, I prefixed the def and use of `gridData` and `genSpline` with:

```
global gridData genSpline;
```

... as the documentation seems to suggest. However, this fails with:

```
'Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.'
```

... in `bar.m`. Reverting to passing via arguments proves that there is nothing wrong with `interPts`. Printlining the def and use of the version with the global variable gives this:

`wrapper.m`:

```
  genSpline = 
    griddedInterpolant with properties:
                GridVectors: {[1x41 double]  [1x41 double]  [1x12 double]}
                     Values: [41x41x12 double]
                     Method: 'spline'
        ExtrapolationMethod: 'spline'
```

`bar.m`:

```
  genSpline =
       []
```

... implying that either the global variable isn't being set properly, or for some reason is inaccessible to `bar.m`. There is no distributed network involved, and all files are within the same directory, which is on the MATLAB (R2014a 64-bit UNIX) path. Any suggestions?

PS: The same approach towards declaring and using global variables works with a 'regular' 2x2 matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The MATLAB workers in a parallel pool are completely separate processes, and as such you cannot share data from the client simply by declaring it to be `global`. You might be able to use a [shared matrix](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28572-sharedmatrix) to solve this.

Comment: `sharedmatrix` does not seem to support sharing `griddedInterpolant` either.